# How to swipe back to the initial condition after let or right swipe in android?

Tags: android

below is my code. I am able to swipe right and left. But the problem is once i swipe left or right that's it I can't again swipe right or left to go back to the initial condition. For example, First i will have list of text view then if i swipe left then i will get one icon and the text view will be gone.So now i need to swipe right to get back the textview and that time icon should be gone. How can i do that?

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList countries =  new ArrayList<>();
        private DataAdapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
        private EditText et_country;
        private int edit_position;
        private View view;
        private boolean add = false;
        private Paint p = new Paint();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initViews();
        }

        private void initViews(){
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapter = new DataAdapter(countries);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            initSwipe();

        }
        private void initSwipe(){
            final ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ) {

                @Override
                public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    if( direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                    Bitmap icon;
                    if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

                        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                        float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                        float width = height / 3;

                        if(dX < 0) {
                            p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                            RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                            c.drawRect(background,p);
                            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selectedicon);
                            RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                            c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);

                        } else {
                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                            RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                            c.drawRect(background,p);
                            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selectedicon);
                            RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                            c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);

                        }
                    }
                    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }
            };

            ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(dX < 0) {
                            p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                            RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                            c.drawRect(background,p);
                            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selectedicon);
                            RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                            c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                            dX = 0;

                        }
```

The code above applies to swipe left and then swipe right to get back to the initial state.

Answer (score -1):

```
     @Override
                    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

                        return true;
                    }

    change it to return false

@Override
                    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

                        return false;
                    }
```

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I went through you code but you have not provided data in "countries"
adapter = new DataAdapter(countries);

can you post your code in detail.

Comment: That's okay. I have got the answer.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to set Onclick listeners to the icon whic is inside the onChildDraw method